# How should I consume a configuration entity on partner portal?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-portals

`Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords` is available on CRM form.

Is there any way to query web api from the javascript on webpages?

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Comment: No @ArunVinoth.

Comment: if my answer helped you, pls upvote/accept to help others find it useful

Comment: Since the answer helped I am marking this as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot use `Xrm.WebApi` in portals and they are native to CRM forms.

Recently web api is [introduced for portals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/web-api-overview) and you can use it for CUD operations from portal. [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/web-api-perform-operations) and this [blog post](https://www.dancingwithcrm.com/powerapps-portal-web-api-deep-dive/) can help you to understand and setup the pre-requisites like enabling settings, permissions, verbose.

For entity data retrieval - still we have to use `fetchxml` liquid tag. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/liquid/template-tags#fetchxml)